# android studio java言語で同じ画像(ImageView)を使いまわしたい

Tags: android, java, android-studio, 画像

android studio java言語でボードゲームアプリを作成しています。
同じ画像をタップするたびに表示したいのですが方法がわかりません。
イメージは、リバーシのようにタップした位置に画像を表示させ、かつ前に表示した画像は
消えずに残るというものを作成したいです。
使いまわす回数は最大で２００回ほどになるため、
それに耐えうる実装であると嬉しいです。

どのようなレイアウトで作成すればよいのか全く分からないためソースなどはありませんが、
～を使えば可能である、など方法を教えていただければ幸いです。

環境：android studio 3.1.2
　　　java言語

Answer (score 1):

恐らく、user28444さんがやりたいことをするのに必要であるのはリソース画像の使いまわしであり、ImageViewの使いまわしでは無いと思います。裏表２種類のリソース画像と、ボードゲームに必要な数のImageView、例えばリバーシなら64個のImageView、そしてImageViewを適切な位置に配置するためのLinearLayoutなどの親ビューがあれば良いです。

とっつきやすさから考えると、LinearLayoutで練習されるのをお勧めします。例としてリバーシの場合で考えますが、一番大本のLinearLayoutを作りその中に8個のLinearLayoutを入れます。そして各LinearLayoutに8個ずつ正方形のImageViewを入れてください。あとは、各ImageViewにタッチリスナ等を設定して、タップで表裏のリソース画像が切り替わるようにすれば良いです。